# Trying to download a image file from api response

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to download a file from apiresponse which is coming as:

[image]

I tried using cfcontent but it is going into some loop

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=myfile.png">
<cfcontent type="application/octet-stream" reset="Yes" variable=#fileReadBinary(objects.rawData)#>
```

it also shows in here

[image]

Comment: Comment out the cfheader/cfcontent for now.  What indication do you have that you were able to obtain an image file from this api?

Comment: because i am connecting to aws and running the getobject method and passing thekey and key is an image file, i already commented the cfcontent

Comment: Are you using getAsBinary=true? Iirc, that should return a binary array. If not, call toByteArray to get the binary

Comment: but where exactly call the toByteArray, in the cfcontent

Comment: I don't actually know, but either instead of or in conjunction with fileReadBinary is what I would try.

Comment: If you look at your dump, it is a method of the rawdata object. So use `<cfcontent variable=objects.rawData.toByteArray() ...>` However, you didn't say whether you're using cfhhtp getAsBinary=true? Ideally, the result would already be a byte array, so cfcontent could use it directly, like this  `cfcontent variable=objects.rawData ...`

Comment: i am not using the `getasbinary` and can't use it

Comment: post it as an answer @SOS . I can accept your answer

Comment: `i am not using the getasbinary and can't use it` Why not?